# MAUI .NET 7 does not show anything after integrating MauiMTAdmob 1.0.4

Tags: xaml, admob, maui

My MAUI project uses Net7. After following instructions in this [Link](https://www.mauiexpert.it/admob-for-maui-made-easy/), my project show nothing in the body screen (like a blank page), only the title "Home".

I have tried remove MTAdView control in that xaml page but nothing changed.
If anyone has encountered a similar situation and found a solution, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Thank you for reading

Comment: I have a similar issue with the interstitial. It doesn't show when I want to show it. It seems a lot of people complain about it, not just for the component itself but with Google for the native advs.